# Is it possible to create too many tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a concept that I want to put in place.  It is for a business logic layer of our software.  our application can literally insert thousands of records at a time.  I simply want to take the JSON I get Import that to a table then use a stored procedure to import the data.  So every save our system does could potentially create a table actual table named by GUID processes the data then deletes it.. I am wondering if this will cause negative affects on our database.

Comment: Why not just use the stored proc to import the JSON to the final table and skip the whole "load it into a temp table" thing? Surely that's more efficient than creating a new temporary table, inserting into that, inserting from the temp table to the permanent table, then tearing down the temp table.

Comment: @CanSpice: parsing this (like parsing XML) will be ugly and/or expensive in SQL. I'd prefer to parse before sending to SQL Server...

Comment: @CanSpice  gbn is correct it isn't as fast because it has to be parsed so its better to just bulk import using the Jet driver and getting it in there then you can use SQL power and speed to batch insert and manipulate your data to get it inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepare a temp table before calling the stored procedure rather than a persistent table. This way, every process can use the same name: otherwise you'll need a lot of dynamic SQL.

You can use SQLBulkCopy into this temp table or into the real table directly

Note: for SQL Server 2008 you have [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

And 1000s in one go is what RDBMS are designed to do...

Comment: I have had situations where I have used table variables and over 20k records those table variables end up eating my page-file and just eating memory and rendered the whole thing useless.  I found creating an actual table was much faster.  While i have used temp tables, i just washed my hands of the whole things because it seemed a similar scenario but i didn't research it much. so i ended up writing dynamic SQL and using a table all the time.  But if i do a single # that is connection specific is it not?  WHich would solve my problem but your saying i wouldn't cause myself any other issues?

Comment: @Rico #tablename acts mostly like a real table. I have used this technique to good effect

Answer (score 0):

If they are [temporary tables](http://www.programmers-corner.com/article/76), I don't see a problem. Just don't try to do this with permanent tables.

That said, there is probably a better way to accomplish whatever you are doing without resorting to creating a table each time. If you explain more what you are trying to do we might be able to help with an alternate solution that would perform better.

Comment: John, We have a scenario where we have a lot of business logic that we want to feed all of our data through, whether it be for webservice imports batch excel imports, or just daily use of the application.  We don't want when the core business logic changes for an object to have to go through and change 20 other components.  The reality is you can't get away completely but what we can do is put in place a lightning fast way to insert, update and delete mass amounts of data.  This style was my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deleting the tables, then you're not "Creating too many". Obviously every system has limits, so "yes" it's possible to create "too many tables". But if you're talking about 100,000 tables created and destroyed over time, them "no".

Many DBs, for example, have the concept of the "temporary" table, which is no more than a table who's life span is tied to the life of the connection. So these tables are created and destroyed routinely.

So, using a normal table in this fashion should be no problem.